# [0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Materialized views cannot be defined on pg tables.;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Redshift has recently introduced support of materialised views for external tables as stated [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-redshift-materialized-views-support-external-tables/).

What I noticed is that it works when I query an external table based on unloaded data in Parquet format (via Redshift utility UNLOAD), for example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_materialised_view AS (
    select id
    from external_schema.parquet_based_table);
```

But when I use a data source composed of complex JSONs

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_materialised_view AS (
    select id
    from external_schema.json_based_table);
```

I receive this error message:

```
[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Materialized views cannot be defined on pg tables.;
```

For which I really have no idea how to deal with. Any idea on what's wrong and what's generating this error message?

Answer (score 1):

I've been in contact with AWS Support and I've been told it is a known issue: parsing nested JSON data is not supported yet and raises this exception.

They are working on it and hopefully will be soon sorted out.

UPDATE [2020-11-20]

Out of curiosity I re-executed the query that was causing this exception and today it worked. Unfortunately I didn't find any update online on this being fixed